# What does a program's capacity mean, and how can I use it?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, sr4-matrix

Using chummer, after I added a new program, I noticed it says "capacity" in the properties of the program.
This feature increases when upgrading from rating 3 to rating 4. I wasn't able to find any reference in the core book and the supplementals.

Can anybody explain this? or do you have any idea as to the use of it?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this is explained in *Unwired* on page 114: capacity is just a measurement of the maximum amount of program options available.